# Unable to use PySpark with oozie

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, oozie, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently trying to trigger and schedule some PySpark jobs using Oozie. My cluster is using HDP 2.6 with Ambari.

I created my Workflow with SparkAction, but when try to run, I got the following error:

```
 Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:222)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:58)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
```

**workflow.xml:**

```
<workflow-app name="PySpark" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5"> <global>
 <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>oozie.launcher.yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
        <value>PYSPARK_ARCHIVES_PATH=pyspark.zip</value>
     </property>
 </configuration> </global>
 <start to="spark-846b"/>
 <kill name="Kill">
     <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
 </kill>
 <action name="spark-846b">
     <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
         <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
         <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
         <master>${master}</master>
         <name>MyApp</name>
         <jar>${nameNode}/analysis/000001/oozie/dummy.py</jar>
         <spark-opts>--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhdp.version=2.6.1.0-129 --conf spark.yarn.archive=hdfs://hadoop1.hadoopcwb:8020/hdp/apps/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz --py-files pyspark.zip,py4j-0.10.4-src.zip</spark-opts>
     </spark>
     <ok to="End"/>
     <error to="Kill"/>
 </action>
 <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

**job.properties:**

```
nameNode=hdfs://hadoop1.hadoopcwb:8020
jobTracker=hadoop1.hadoopcwb:8032
master=yarn-cluster
queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/analysis/000001/oozie
```

**job python**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from operator import add

def main():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```